# What is the asymptotic notations of commonly used Image Interpolation algorithms?

Tags: image, image-processing, time, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I would like to know the Asymptotic big O notations of the following Image Interpolation Algorithms. since multiple literatures were giving confusing information about this, I can't come to a conclusion.
1. Bilinear 2. Bicubic 3. lanczos3 4. lanczos2

Comment: What is your N? the number of pixels in the image?

Comment: pixel resoulution is 240x320 depth image obtained from kinect v1

Comment: I think you are not looking for asymptotic behivor because all of them are O(N). You are looking for an exact complexity. The complexity of each one of them will be tbe basic function that the use times the number of pixels. So for example bilrniar calculation for each pixel is something like four additions and 8 multiplications so roughly 12 operations per pixel. What you need to do is just look at each interpolation and deconstruct it to its basic operations.

Comment: i heard that its not same, with lanczos3 taking 32 pixels into considerations, please explain me correctly